# a specific type should write messages in a separate logfile

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I use the following configuration for log4net:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\WebPortal.API.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <threshold value="ALL" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{2} - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I can now get a logger like this and use it:

```
static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(OperationsPlanningService));
```

Now, I want to write loggings from one specific type in a separate log-file. When I create a logger with `typeof(ExceptionHandlingMiddleware)` like this:

```
static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ExceptionHandlingMiddleware));
```

the messages from this logger should be written in logs\WebPortal.ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.log

Is this possible with log4net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add specific configurations for specific loggers the same as for the root logger in the XML like:

```
<logger name="MyLoggerName">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="MyAppender" />
</logger>
```

MyLoggerName could be the full logger name or just the namespace or even part of the namespace (log4net loggers form a hierarchy).